# Get last 24 hours data from SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all i want to select from my table all records from last 24h , 7days , 14 days ....( my sql timespan format is date("l, M d Y, h:i:s A"))  so when i try to receive the data from last 24h is not working for me any help plz
exemple
if i get all date from

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats");
```

result is Day,Date,time Count

```
Saturday, Feb 27 2016, 02:28:59 PM 27191 Saturday, Feb 27 2016, 03:28:05 PM 28659 Saturday, Feb 27 2016, 04:27:26 PM 30138
```

so i try like that and not working any help plz

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE timespan >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

Comment: **Stop** using depicates `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: What is the datatype of timespan column? Is it date or varchar?

Comment: varchar

 CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timespan` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM stats WHERE STR_TO_DATE(timespan,"%W, %b %d %Y, %h:%i:%s %p") >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

STR_TO_DATE will convert your the string into date format (Y-m-d H:i:s) and then you can compare it with the date returned by now()

Comment: i just tested and i dont get any resulte is blank page ps my send data is date("l, M d Y, h:i:s A"))

Comment: Fixed and here the fix 

SELECT * FROM stats WHERE STR_TO_DATE(count,\"%W, %b %d %Y, %h:%i:%s %p\") >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Make sure "timespan" exists and that it is a date. According to your example you should test on the "date" field.